what is exactly the meaning of fairness in MPC?
According to this paper ,

Gordon, D., Hazay, C., Katz, J., Lindell, Y.: Complete fairness in
secure two-party computation. In: Proc. 40th Annual ACM Symposium on
Theory of Computing (STOC) (2008)

the definition of complete fairness of MPC protocol is that

either all parties receive the protocol output or
no party does.

My question is if an adversary can cause honest parties to obtain an incorrect output while it obtains a correct output, is this scenario covered by the definition of fairness?
Or does the requirement of fairness merely ensure that the premature abort actions of malicious parties do not affect whether honest parties can obtain outputs?
